# Lines from document.write vanish

Tags: javascript, arrays

My code produces these two lines first:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
```

Then it produces these lines, and those two disappear:

```
1,2,3
1,2
1
```

Why is this happening?

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];

document.write(arr+"</br>");

function popit() {
    if(arr.length>0) {
        arr.pop();
        if(arr.length<=0) {
            clearTimeout(p);
            document.write("end");
        }
        var p=setTimeout(popit,1000);
        document.write(arr);
        document.write("</br>");
    }
}
window.onLoad=popit();
```

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `document.write()` after the page has finished loading, which you are, by using `window.onLoad=popit()`, it will essentially clear the HTML of the body and start adding new content. Don't use `document.write()`. If you have to output to the screen, add to `document.body.innerHTML`.

Alternatively, you could just `console.log(arr)`